# Probability ordering by seller's tariff

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have an instance method which calculates the position of an element, depending on the tariff of its seller.

If the seller is of a `level3` tariff, it gets to top 100, the probability of 40%. If the tariff is `level2`, then 30%, etc.

```
TARIFFS = {level3: 0...40,
           level2: 40...70,
           level1: 70...90,
           level0: 90..100}

def update_priority
  top = 100
  priority = 0
  random = rand(0..top)
  all_count = collection.find.count
  if TARIFFS[seller.tariff] === random
    priority = rand((all_count - top).to_f..all_count.to_f)
  else
    priority = rand(1..all_count)
  end

  collection.find(_id: self._id).update('$set' => {priority: priority})
end
```

And I have class method which runs every 2 hours:

```
def recalculate_priorities
  unscoped.each(&:update_priority)
end
```

It does not work fast. How can I optimize it to work faster?

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: I'm assuming `collection` and `unscoped` are some sort of `Enumerable` objects.

The key to improving performance is to not do any unnecessary work. You're doing quite a bit of unnecessary work in `#update_priority`.

`all_count = collection.find.count` creates an `Enumerator` that isn't used. Let's get rid of that.

`all_count = collection.find.count` calculates the size is of that enumerator inefficiently. `#count` iterates the collection and counts how many elements it has. It is an `O(n)` operation. `#size` on the other hand, doesn't iterate the collection. It is an `O(1)` operation.

If this only happened once, this wouldn't be so bad, but this happens for **every** element of `unscoped`. Suppose `unscoped` has `100` elements and `collection` has `1000` elements. We're doing the same calculation a `100` times. That's a `100,000` unnecessary iterations! We can do better: only calculate the size *once* in `#recalculate_priorities`.

`collection.find(_id: self._id).update('$set' => {priority: priority})` suffers from a similar problem. For each `unscoped` element at least `1` database query is performed. Again, we can do better: use a single query to update many records at once (a batch query) in `#recalculate_priorities`.

I've written some example code below. As I don't know any MongoDB, I made up an API for it.

```
def new_priority(collection_size)
  top      = 100
  priority = 0
  random   = rand(top)

  if TARIFFS[seller.tariff].cover?(random)
    lower = collection_size - top
    upper = collection_size

    return rand(lower..upper) # Floats are unnecessary
  else
    return rand(1..collection_size)
  end
end

def recalculate_priorities
  new_priorities = unscoped.map { |el| el.new_priority(collection.size) }

  unscoped.update(:priority => new_priorities)
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Good idea!
But _unscoped.update(:priority => new_priorities)_  does not keep order.